# How To Run UI Test Classes Using Selenium Webdriver in Jenkins?

Tags: testing, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I have test classes written in java for UI testing using Maven using Selenium Web-Driver. I want to run them using mvn test command in Jenkins.
It is not able to launch the browser for the testing.

The error stack shown is something like this:
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
Error: no display specified
Error: no display specified
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:106)

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox needs a X display to run, e.g. Xvfb

You will need to

- install xvfb on your server. Doing this depends on your server operating system (and package management)
- start xvfb before the build. You can do this using the [xfvb plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xvfb+Plugin), or by running Xvfb as a daemon. I personally like to use the plugin.